# Why is this function (complex) not analytic at zero?

Tags: complex-analysis

$$f(x+iy) = |x| + i|y|.$$
Noting that $f$ is defined on an open set $\mathbb{C}$, with CR equations

$$u_x = \operatorname{sgn}(x), u_y = 0 $$

$$v_x = 0, v_y = \operatorname{sgn}(y).$$

So we require $u_x = v_v \iff xy\geq 0$.

The solutions exlude $0$ but I don't see why.

Comment: $f(z) = z$ for $\Re(z) \ge 0, \Im(z) \ge 0$ and $f(z) = \overline{z}$ for $\Re(z) \ge 0,\Im(z) < 0$. Can you finish ?

Comment: Hmm I'm not really seeing it; should I prove that it is not differentiable?

Comment: $g(z) = \overline{z}$ is real-differentiable (and real analytic) but not **complex differentiable** this is well-known.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- $g(z)$ is **complex differentiable** at $z=c$ iff $f(z+c) = f(c) + a z  + o(|z|)$ (so we can say $a = f'(c)$)
- With $g(z) = \overline{z}$ you obtain $g(z+c) = g(c) + \color{red}{\overline{z}} +o(|z|)$. Thus it is not complex-differentiable.
- Here $f(z) = z$ for $\Im(z) \ge 0, \Re(z) \ge 0$ and $f(z) = \overline{z}$ for $\Im(z) \le 0, \Re(z) \ge 0$.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote $u_x = \operatorname{sgn}(x)$, but actually that only holds for $x \ne 0$.  (The real function $|x|$ is not differentiable at $0$.) Similarly for $v_y = \operatorname{sgn}(y)$.

Answer (score 0):

For $z=x+iy$ we have

$\frac{f(z)-f(0)}{z-0}=1$ if $x,y>0$

and

$\frac{f(z)-f(0)}{z-0}=-1$ if $x,y<0$.